# Can we have automatic conversion of Stack Exchange URLs into question titles on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, internal-links

There is this interesting feature in the Stack Exchange posts consisting on having a link converted into the question's title. For example:

- if I type `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1983854`
- it gets converted into the link "How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?" pointing to `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1983854`
- see the magic: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1983854)

This has [some limitations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/209901), but basically every SE site will have their links to their own questions expanded.

However, I see this is missing in Stack Overflow for Teams. Could we have it implemented as well?

Comment: Is this request for links in team Q&A to public SO questions to be converted, or for links in team Q&A to the same team's private Q&A converted?

Comment: @BenVoigt Good question. I prefer both :)

Comment: @BenVoigt since every SO for Teams tend to be something unattached to any other SE site, I was thinking on having this just for the same team's private Q&A. However, having public SO questions converted could be also beneficial (I imagine someone answering a question and giving a link to some public SO as a reference).